# Can I let myself out of a prison if I buy the prison?

Tags: united-states, prison

Let's say I'm convicted of a felony and sent to state prison. Then, I buy the prison.

Can I just let myself out?

Comment: You may be surpised to learn this, but prison owners aren't the ones deciding who stays in prison.

Comment: If you have enough money to buy a prison, you're not going to be sent to prison in the US.

Comment: @Studoku Bernie Madoff could easily afford a prison

Comment: Similar but not exactly the same, Pablo Escobar's [La Catedral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Catedral) prison was built by Escobar to imprison him, and was basically a fortress surrounding a palace.  He made a prior agreement with the Columbian government though.

Comment: They can't let themselves out, but they probably can ensure they're not mistreated by the guards, and trade on that influence with other prisoners.

Comment: Don't you need some clearance in order to operate a prison in the US ?

Comment: @Strawberry The point of his conviction was that, actually, no he couldn't. That's kinda the whole shtick of Ponzi schemes.

Comment: @fraxinus To operate, probably, but to own, not likely. Owner and operator are two separate business roles. You can be the 'owner' of a business or organization and be in prison; there's no law against that, in general.

Comment: @Strawberry yes, but he pissed off a lot of other rich people, so that option was out.

Comment: Have you just moved some Bitcoins by any chance?

Comment: Probably cheaper to buy a judge.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Not legally.  Private prisons are operated under a government mandate (typically via a contract with the government).

That said, depending on jurisdiction, there are plenty of scenarios where a prisoner is legally permitted to leave a prison.  This can include work release programs, work details controlled by the prison, to visit sick or ill relatives, as part of a rehabilitation program (e.g., to attend an education program), etc.

How much of these forms of release can be manipulated by a private prison likely varies by jurisdiction.  Of course, some of the relevant decision makers may have a preference for keeping the prison owner happy, even if the owner has no direct influence.

Mind you, it is probably difficult to get into such a position.  I suspect a prison operator would not be sent to their own prison (and would not want to be; prisoners might attack them).  Similarly, the government would probably block a jailed felon from taking ownership of their own prison.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if a prison owner got sent to the most wanton "gen-pop" area of his own prison in this case. It is a crazy hypothetical - but hte prison can of course decide where in the prison to put a particular prisoner. Wing A is for the owner, Wing B is for the rest... They can also waive any self imposed arrival procedures. The owner gets to keep his shivs, so to say.

Comment: @StianYttervik There's also a subtle, but important, difference between a guy who owns a prison being sent to his own prison and the scenario OP described: of a prisoner taking ownership of the prison he's already in. Setting aside the question of whether the law would *allow* this, of course. In the latter case, he was a prisoner *first,* and depending on his existing relationships with other prisoners (and his willingness to do them favours) the purchase of the prison could make him *better liked* rather than hated. The underdog is taking power, rather than the powerful being exposed.

Comment: Let's say a billionaire goes to prison for some white-collar crime.  He doesn't like the food.  Buys the prison, improves the food.  Probably wouldn't be attacked for that action.

Comment: Prisoners who get to leave prisons for parole, for example, must pass an exam/interview with a *state* (or federal) review board... even if the prison is a private one. [Studies have shown](https://time.com/3928184/private-prisons-longer-incarceration/) that prisoners in private prisons have longer sentences because they incur more infractions due to private prison staff being less trained and less well-paid compared to state prisons.

Comment: @TylerH Ah, great, add it to the pile of why private prisons suck more than regular pirsons.